# Linq Group by with nested collection throwing Cannot perform an aggregate function

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, collections

I want to do something like this:

```
        var projectHistory = await Context.Tasks.GroupBy(x => x.ProjectId).Select(x => new ProjectHistoryStatModel
        {
            ProjectId = x.Key,
            CompletedTasks = x.Where(y => y.StatusId == 4).Count(),
            InProgressTasks = x.Where(y => y.StatusId == 3).Count(),
            DelayedTasks = x.Where(y => y.EndDate < DateTime.Now && y.StatusId != 4).Count(),
            DependentTasks = x.Where(y => y.Dependents.Any()).Count(),
            TotalTasks = x.Count()
        }).ToListAsync();
```

But DependentTasks property `DependentTasks = x.Where(y => y.Dependents.Any()).Count(),`  is throwing:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Well y.Dependents is a Collection that is why its throwing the problem, I also tried this: `DependetTasks = Context.TaskDependencies.Where(y => x.Any(z => z.Id == y.TaskId)).Count(),` and it throws the same error.

Can you guys show me a way of doing this in the same request to the DB?

Regards

Comment: Please specify which ORM do you use and which version.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using EF Core < 6.0, you can try to rewrite your query in the following way:

```cs
var query = 
    from t in Context.Tasks
    group new { t, HasDependents = t.Dependents.Any() } by t.ProjectId into g
    select new ProjectHistoryStatModel
    {
        ProjectId = g.Key,
        CompletedTasks = g.Where(y => y.t.StatusId == 4).Count(),
        InProgressTasks = g.Where(y => y.t.StatusId == 3).Count(),
        DelayedTasks = g.Where(y => y.t.EndDate < DateTime.Now && y.t.StatusId != 4).Count(),
        DependentTasks = g.Where(y => y.HasDependents).Count(),
        TotalTasks = g.Count()
    };

var projectHistory = await query.ToListAsync();
```

EF Core up to 6.0 do not support translating navigation properties after `GroupBy`.